# What does "providing a delegate" mean in the context of a lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

I have a definition of the :: operator in Java as:

> The double colon (::) operator, i.e. method reference operator, is
> used to call a method by referring to it with the help of its class
> directly. They behave the same as lambda expressions. The only
> difference is this uses direct reference to the method by name instead
> of providing a delegate to the method.

Can someone please help to explain the last part - i.e. *"instead of providing a delegate to the method"*. What does this part mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(object-oriented_programming)) is when one object has a method which simply calls an equivalent method on another object; so for example, in the class below, the method `foo` is delegated to the object `obj`:

```java
class Example {
    private final Bar obj;
    public Example(Bar obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    public Baz foo(Qux x) {
        return obj.foo(x);
    }
}
```

A lambda expression like `x -> obj.foo(x)` is syntactically similar to `return obj.foo(x);`, and the evaluation of the lambda expression creates an object with a method which delegates the `foo` method to the object `obj`, which is semantically similar to `new Example(obj)`. So this is an example of delegation.

Of course, `obj::foo` *also* (semantically) creates an object with a method which delegates the `foo` method to the object `obj`. So the text you quoted seems debatable; the quote does at least say the behaviour is the same, so perhaps what the author means is that the lambda syntactically resembles delegation whereas the method reference does not (because it's in [point-free style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming)). At least, this seems to be what the quote *means*.

---

To pre-empt the debate about whether lambdas and method references really create objects: if you use a debugger then you might discover some implementation details which suggest otherwise, but the Java Language Specification says, authoritatively, that ([§15.27.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4))

> At run time, evaluation of a lambda expression is similar to evaluation of a class instance creation expression, insofar as normal completion produces a reference to an object. [...] Either a new instance of a class with the properties below is allocated and initialized, or an existing instance of a class with the properties below is referenced.

and ([§15.13.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3))

> At run time, evaluation of a method reference expression is similar to evaluation of a class instance creation expression, insofar as normal completion produces a reference to an object. [...] either a new instance of a class with the properties below is allocated and initialized, or an existing instance of a class with the properties below is referenced.

Comment: Currently, there is indeed one more level of delegation with `x -> obj.foo(x)` as it creates an object that delegates to the synthetic method holding the lambda body which delegates to the target method. The method reference does not, except when it does, e.g. for varargs methods or `super::method` etc. It’s best not to worry about these implementation details and instead, focus on the relevant differences, e.g. `obj::foo` throwing *immediately* if `obj` is `null` or `flatMap(Pattern.compile(…)::splitAstream)` saving a lot of work compared to `flatMap(x -> Pattern.compile(…).splitAstream(x))`

Answer (score 2):

It means that you can reference a method, for example like this:

```
myList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

... instead of having the write a lambda and make a call to the method:

```
myList.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

Comment: Ok - got it. So i is the 'delegate' (i.e. it is some dummy helper variable) and :: syntax allows us to not need to use it?

Comment: Not really, delegation is when a method wraps another method.

Comment: In this case the lambda wraps the `System.out.println`. `forEach` is an existing method on the collection interface which accepts a higher order function (either lambda or method reference).

Comment: The lambda `i -> System.out.println(i)` wraps a simple call to `System.out::pintln`.

Comment: I understand this part but can you clarify on the "The only difference is this uses direct reference to the method by name instead of providing a delegate to the method." in your example

Comment: The delegate (in the terminology of the original quote, as I understand it) would be the object resulting from the evaluation of the lambda expression. If you wrote something like `Consumer<Foo> delegate = i -> System.out.println(i);` then `delegate` would be (a reference to) the delegate.

Comment: Thank you both! I understand it well now; you took it a step further with the 'object resulting from the evaluation' part...this is what I was fuzzy on